# How to force @Transactional to work <jdbcTemplate>?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Can someone tell me why my entityTransaction doesn't works?
rollback() has no effect, commit() too, i think also begin(). I tried to disable autocommit:

```
spring.datasource.auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```

but there is no effect after that, still that transactions don't work. Here is my service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    ...
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    ...
    @Transactional
    public ArrayList<String> executeSQL(String[] split) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        ArrayList<String> listException = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
            String query = split[i];
            try {
                entityTransaction.begin();
                mapList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
                entityTransaction.commit();
                listException.add("Success!");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                entityTransaction.rollback();
                try {
                    entityTransaction.begin();
                    int rows = jdbcTemplate.update(query);
                    entityTransaction.commit();
                    listException.add("Sucesss! { [" + rows + "] <-- affected rows }");
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    entityTransaction.rollback();
                    flag = true;
                    listException.add(e2.getCause().getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        entityManager.close();
        if(flag){
            mapList = emptyMapList;
            updateFlag = false;
        }
        else{
            updateFlag = true;
        }
        return listException;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: If you're using the `@Transactional` annotation, why are you trying to commit & rollback manually yourself?

Comment: I need to commit&rollback manually because my "query" is sometimes "create" / sometimes "select" ect. and that "queryForList()" giving me errors if i will put "create"  into query. If i will remove that addnotation it won't work too.

Comment: To make @Transactional work - you need to enable Transactions..  are you using xml config or java configuratons ? You many need to enable transactionmanager via xml or java configuation class. Regarding EntityManagerFactory - how is the entityManagerFactory created ? You may need to check if that bean is setup correctly.

Comment: I am using xml config. I created entityManagerFactory by @Autowired.

Comment: try these steps: remove two autocommt settings; remove @transactional and also remove entity manager factory and all manual handling transaction lines. You should also call appropiate method of jdbc template without try catch (inspect your query and choose correct method)